# How to pass some sort of generic closure to a function to generate specific values

Tags: generics, closures, rust

This is my first Rust project. I am working on a genetic programming API and I thought it would be neat if the genes on base pairs (in this case instructions) could be made generic (this is a Multi-Expression Program).

```
pub struct Mep<Ins> {
    instructions: Vec<Ins>,
}
```

I attempt to make a new function that takes a closure to generate `Ins` in the vector:

```
impl<Ins> Mep<Ins> {
    //Generates a new Mep with a particular size and takes a closure to generate random instructions
    pub fn new<F>(total_instructions: usize, random_instruction_generator: F) -> Mep<Ins>
        where F : Fn() -> Ins {
        let mut mep = Mep{instructions: Vec::with_capacity(total_instructions)};
        for _ in 0..total_instructions {
            mep.instructions.push(random_instruction_generator());
        }
        mep
    }
}
```

This builds fine, and appears to work, but the intended use case was not fulfilled. I intended for the user to get access to the state of a PRNG that is reused over many calls to the new and other functions. In my case, this is the problematic situation:

```
...
extern crate rand;
use rand::isaac::Isaac64Rng;
use rand::SeedableRng;
use rand::Rng;
#[test]
fn mep_new() {
    let mut rng = Isaac64Rng::from_seed(&[1, 2, 3, 4]);
    let len = 80;
    let a: Mep<u32> = Mep::new(len, || rng.next_u32());
}
```

I create a new PRNG and then wish to capture a mutable reference to it in the closure. Rust complains with this compilation error:

```
tests/mep.rs:12:40: 12:43 error: cannot borrow data mutably in a captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure [E0387]
tests/mep.rs:12     let a: Mep<u32> = Mep::new(len, || rng.next_u32());
                                                       ^~~
```

I found that [this post](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2012-May/001810.html) infers that the [closure capture syntax](http://www.rust-ci.org/Kimundi/capture.rs/doc/capture/) has been moved into this new form. So I attempted this:

```
#[test]
fn mep_new() {
    let mut rng = Isaac64Rng::from_seed(&[1, 2, 3, 4]);
    let len = 80;
    let a: Mep<u32> = Mep::new(len, |ref rng| rng.next_u32());
}
```

But the compiler complains:

```
tests/mep.rs:12:51: 12:61 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
tests/mep.rs:12     let a: Mep<u32> = Mep::new(len, |ref rng| rng.next_u32());
                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
tests/mep.rs:12:23: 12:31 error: type mismatch: the type `[closure@tests/mep.rs:12:37: 12:61]` implements the trait `core::ops::Fn<([type error],)>`, but the trait `core::ops::Fn<()>` is required (expected (), found tuple) [E0281]
tests/mep.rs:12     let a: Mep<u32> = Mep::new(len, |ref rng| rng.next_u32());
                                      ^~~~~~~~
```

Should I be doing this differently? Is an iterator a better thing to pass to the new function? I would prefer not passing a generic parameter (in this case the PRNG) from new to the closure just to solve this problem. What is a clean way to solve this problem? Instructions will come in different formats and thus need to be generated as such. Alternatively, I can encode a specific instruction format, but I would like to see this generic approach work so I can use the same code for multiple instruction formats, taking advantage of Rust's capabilities.

Comment: Note that both of your links are very old in Rust terms. Rust 1.0 was released 2015-05-15, and info from before the 1.0 betas is usually suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary change you need to make is to alter your generic bound from `Fn` to `FnMut`. Once you've done that, you need to make your parameter `random_instruction_generator` mutable as well:

```
struct Mep<Ins> {
    instructions: Vec<Ins>,
}

impl<Ins> Mep<Ins> {
    fn new<F>(total_instructions: usize, mut random_instruction_generator: F) -> Mep<Ins>
        where F: FnMut() -> Ins
    {
        let instructions =
            (0..total_instructions)
            .map(|_| random_instruction_generator())
            .collect();

        Mep {
            instructions: instructions,
        }
    }
}

struct FakeRng;
impl FakeRng {
    // https://xkcd.com/221/
    fn next_u32(&mut self) -> u32 { 4 }
}

fn main() {
    let mut rng = FakeRng;
    let a = Mep::new(80, || rng.next_u32());
}
```

I also changed your `where` clause to use a bit more standard formatting and used `map` and `collect` instead of having a mutable vector.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am still adapting from C++ and thus also glad to see how iterators are used in this situation in Rust. It is quite radically different, so I never would have thought to return the Mep that way! The copy elision potential in Rust is strong. I will also look out for more standard formatting practices in Rust.

Comment: *how iterators are used in this situation* — one thing I've learned from languages with good iterators is that it's rare to need a mutable container. Also, in many cases you only need a `for` loop as a place to cause side-effects. *more standard formatting practices* — eventually, [rustfmt](https://github.com/nrc/rustfmt) will be the easy solution to getting consistent formatting. ^_^